# Error Installing web3js for Ethereum / Unable to connect to github.com

Tags: npm, ethereum, web3js

I'm using npm to install web3js:

```
npm install web3
```

It eventually fails. Here is the output I get...

```
npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: â ï¸  WARNING â ï¸ tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/frozeman/WebSocket-Node.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 192.30.255.113]: errno=Connection timed out
npm ERR! github.com[1: 192.30.255.112]: errno=Connection timed out
```

Here is some version info:

```
uname -a
Linux bde2744830c3 4.1.12-103.7.1.el7uek.x86_64

npm --version 
5.5.1
```

I've scoured SO and other sites that have somewhat similar postings, but nothing that offers help. I've tried

```
npm cache verify
```

To no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the repo url using the git protocol (`git://`) instead of http. Please make sure you have inbound port 9418 open for it to work.

Hope that helps.